# php fwrite returns the correct value but something is wrong

Tags: php, laravel, fwrite

I had build a big file uploader in php based on Larevel 5.5.I divided a big file into pieces, each piece size is 2M.

I received all pieces on web sever, and check all pieces' md5. Everything is right. But when I contacted all pieces, something went wrong. The final file's md5 is differ with the source file. And I compared two files in binary, the last three chunks' content is differ with souce file, since pieces md5 is right.

I think the key is fwrite function, but I logged the output of fwrite, it always return the bytes it wrote which is right.

I'd tried my best, but the problem still exist, can you help me?

```php
$uploadFile = SUploadFile::where('md5', $md5)->with('chunks')->first();
if ( empty($uploadFile) ) {
    return ret(RESOURCE_ERR_NOT_FOUND, 'md5 file not exist');
}
if ( $uploadFile->chunks->count() != $uploadFile->chunks_count ) {
    return ret(-1, "file chunks upload not complete ({$uploadFile->chunks->count()}/{$uploadFile->chunks_count})");
}
$targetPath = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->relativeSavePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $md5);
$file = @fopen($targetPath, 'a');
if (!$file) {
    return ret(-2, 'file operation failed');
}
foreach ($uploadFile->chunks as $chunk) {
    $chunkPath = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->relativeChunkPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $md5 . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $chunk->md5);
    if (!file_exists($chunkPath)) {
        return ret(-2, "chunk {$chunk->md5} does not exist");
    }
    if (fwrite($file, file_get_contents($chunkPath)) === false) {
        fclose($file);
        return ret("contact chunk error，chunk md5={$chunk->md5}");
    }
    fflush($file);
}
fclose($file);
Storage::deleteDirectory($this->relativeChunkPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $md5);
$mime = Storage::mimeType($uploadFile->storage_dir);
$attachment = $uploadFile->attachment()->create([
    'file_name'      => $uploadFile->file_name,
    'md5'            => $uploadFile->md5,
    'file_size'      => $uploadFile->file_size,
    'storage_dir'    => $uploadFile->storage_dir,
    'create_user_id' => $uploadFile->create_user_id,
    'mime'           => $mime
]);
return success_response($attachment->id);
```

Comment: You’re opening your output file in write mode `a` there - have you tried `ab` to make it binary safe? And btw., file_put_contents has a flag to put it into append mode as well, I find that is usually a bit less hassle than the whole fopen/fwrite/fclose procedure.

Comment: After changes fopen mode from 'a' to 'w', it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve it completely. I upload three file chunks at the same time. Since max chunk size is limited to 2M, the last chunk is always smaller than others. So it cost less time to uplaod. Sometimes the last one chunk record in db was in front of the second to last chunk.

Contactting all chunks in the db order sometimes made the contacted file's md5 is diffrent from the source file.

Explicitly order all chunks by chunk id solve this question.
This question can be easily reproduced when last chunk is less than 100kb.